# Correct order of taking dot product and derivatives in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I tried to derive definition of divergence in spherical coordinates from gradient and got:
$${\vec \nabla \cdot \vec A=\bigg (\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\hat r+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\hat \theta+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\hat\phi\bigg)\cdot\bigg(A_{r}\hat r+A_{\theta}\hat \theta+A_{\phi}\hat\phi\bigg)}$$
$${=\frac{\partial A_{r}}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial A_{\theta}}{\partial\theta}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial\phi}}$$
But according to Wikipedia and other sources this be:
$${\vec \nabla \cdot \vec A =\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial (r^2 A_{r})}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial (A_{\theta}\sin\theta)}{\partial\theta}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial\phi}}$$
Why should we first take the derivative and then the dot product?
Why do we take first dot product when we have cartesian coordinates?
I think I read that it is because vectors themselves are functions of the coordinates but I do not understand what are consequences of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your expression:
$$
{\vec \nabla \cdot \vec A=\bigg (\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\hat r+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\hat \theta+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\hat\phi\bigg)\cdot\bigg(A_{r}\hat r+A_{\theta}\hat \theta+A_{\phi}\hat\phi\bigg)} \tag{1}
$$
may be better written:
$$
{\vec \nabla \cdot \vec A=\bigg (\hat r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\hat \theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\hat\phi}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(A_{r}\hat r+A_{\theta}\hat \theta+A_{\phi}\hat\phi\bigg)}  \tag{2}
$$
since the role of the unit vectors in the first parenthesis is static - they give  the coordinate frame in which the components of the nabla operat**or** are expressed at this particular point.

on the other hand, in the second parenthesis, which is the oper**and**, the variation of $\hat r, \hat \theta$ and $\hat \phi$ with $r, \theta$ and $\phi$ must obviously be taken into account when computing the derivatives.

from the relations:
$$
\hat r = \hat x \sin \theta\cos \phi + \hat y \sin \theta \sin \phi - \hat z \cos \theta \\
\hat \theta = \hat x \cos \theta\cos \phi + \hat y \cos \theta \sin \phi - \hat z \sin \theta \\
\hat \phi = -\hat x \sin \phi + \hat y \cos \phi
$$
may be computed the following non-zero derivatives of the curvilinear coordinate unit vectors, allowing the divergence to be evaluated from formula (2) above:
$$
\frac{\partial \hat r}{\partial \theta} = \hat \theta
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \hat r}{\partial \phi} = \hat \phi \sin \theta
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \hat \phi}{\partial \phi} = -(\hat r \sin \theta + \hat \theta \cos \theta)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \hat \theta}{\partial \theta} =- \hat r
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \hat \theta}{\partial \phi} =\hat  \phi \cos \theta
$$